# creating web service client from eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, soap, webservice-client, eclipse-wtp

Hi I am new to SOAP web services and trying to create a client. I am following [This tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/BottomUpWebService/BottomUpWebService.html) but the problem which I am facing is Sometimes it generates the client stub in the form of .java files and sometimes it generates proper client with some .jsp pages like test.jsp, intput.jsp etc.

I have tried searching a lot on internet. Please let me know why it generates two different kind of clients though I am following the same process.

I have generated my client using wsimport but I just want to know, what is causing eclipse to generate two different clients at different times. may be some bug or some detail that I have missed.

Comment: Good question! I always generate stub from WSDL with standard java `wsimport`. [Here is one usefull link for creating web service in Eclipse.](http://pettergraff.blogspot.com/2010/11/developing-web-service-in-eclipse.html)

Comment: @herry thanks for the link, now I also generate my client using wsimport but I just wanted to know, what is causing eclipse to generate two different clients at different times. may be some bug or some detail that we have missed.

Comment: Yes, your question about why Eclipse generate two different clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is most likely caused by selecting a different value in step 6 of the tutorial, when you select which kind of client should be generated: `Move the Client slider to the Test Client position .`

Answer (score 2):

When you run the Eclipse WTP wizard, you get to choose which client you want to have. The JSPs that are generated are simply an input test form to test your web service.

Comment: It's on this page: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/documents/ContributingWebServiceRTWithUI.html